# Driving 2 Stepper Motors using a Quad Motor Driver Shield

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, driver, shield

I've tried driving two [Size 8 Bipolar Nema Stepper Motors](https://www.oyostepper.com/images/upload/File/8HS15-0604S-PG19.pdf) using a Quad Motor Driver Shield from [DFROBOT](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1513.html). I get vibration and noise through the motor but can't get it to move. Is it possible to use this shield in some way to achieve motion in two stepper motors rather than 4 DC motors?

Comment: Schematic and code (use the `{}` button to format it and make sure it's indented and commented properly) required if we're to help you. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: It may be possible, but it might require low level hacking. That device is not designed to drive stepper motors, with the synchronisation between I and Q windings that it requires. Edit - it uses the TB6612, and that is designed to drive 2 indepedent DC motors. Some dual DC motor driver are designed to also be able to drive a two-winding stepper, but not this one.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Some dual DC motor drivers have another mode which can drive a 2-winding stepper. The TB6612 IC that the Quad Motor Shield uses does not have this stepper mode, and only drives independent DC motors.